# Combine consecutive commands into script and run in MAC terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am quite new. Please help.

I have been running 4 consecutive commands for a few times repeatedly whenever I need to test and refresh the database tables.

The 4 commands(shortened just to express the idea) I have been running to reset 2 tables :

```
aws dynamodb delete-table --tableName TableA 
aws dynamodb delete-table --tableName TableB
aws dynamodb create-table --tableName TableA attributeSettingsBlaBlaA
aws dynamodb create-table --tableName TableB attributeSettingsBlaBlaB
```

Is there a way for me to put those 4 commands in a script, such that when I `./combined_script` in MAC terminal will run the 4 commands for me please?

I did a bit research, but `&&` required some copy paste work too. Please teach the `CS` way and help. Thank you.

Sorry I was not being clear. Re-edited. Thanks all for helping.

Comment: You say that the commands are generic. What might be changed from run to run? Just the attribute settings? The table names, too? The number of tables?

Comment: First of all, Mac OS X is off-topic. This site is for Ubuntu only. if you need to ask about something OS X specific, then use apple.stackexchange.com. Second, even if your question *might* work on Ubuntu, you're not being clear what table you're trying to delete/create. Is it MySQL ? is it postgresql ? You're not being clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By MAC, do you mean an Apple Mac?  Anyway, this should still work

```
#!/bin/sh

delete-table --tableName TableA 
delete-table --tableName TableB
create-table --tableName TableA attributeSettingsBlaBlaA
create-table --tableName TableB attributeSettingsBlaBlaB
```

Save that to a file, e.g. `combined_script`, or whatever you like, and be sure to make it executable

```
chmod +x ./combined_script
```

Then it should do what you want. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you're using Ubuntu**

To set it up as its own command that you don't need the preceding `./`, do the following:

Open terminal.

Type

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/[command]
```

(Enter what you want the command to be rather than just [command])

Type

```
#!/bin/sh  
delete-table --tableName TableA  
delete-table --tableName TableB  
create-table --tableName TableA attributeSettingsBlaBlaA  
create-table --tableName TableB attributeSettingsBlaBlaB
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Type

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/[command]
```

Execute the script by typing `[command]`, executable by any user from any directory.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` should be used (see [an on-point answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8658) for why). `/usr/bin` is reserved for things provided by the operating system and Apt, and you should never assume that things you place there won't be clobbered by a new program that happens to use the same executable name or that they won't be deleted wholesale during an OS upgrade.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  Thank you - I will edit my answer and use /usr/local/bin from now on